# How to make sure an apex:enhancedList component displays checkboxes?

Tags: visualforce, list-view

I use an `apex:enhancedList` component on a custom VF page and I want to make sure it always displays checkboxes in the left column, to enable selection of records.

Unfortunately the checkboxes do not always appear: for instance if viewing Accounts and 'Enable Inline Editing' is disabled under Setup->Customize->User Interface

Is there a way to force this component to always display checkboxes, regardless of the org setup?

Update: I created an IdeaExchange idea to make this possible, please vote for it!
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ktiGAAQ

Answer (score 3):

Well, SFDC displays the Checkboxes in the enhanced list view, if

- Your target object doesn't have record types defined OR
- You have defined a filter on a RecordType in the List definition, in the case your object has several RecordTypes defined

There is no other way to "force" displaying checkboxes with >apex:enhancedList>, unfortunately.